# Finding three cells in a matrix with maximum total sum

Tags: algorithm, matrix, brute-force, greedy

I have a greedy solution for the following problem. I want to know how to prove it?

The problem is as follows: Given an *n* x *n* 2D matrix of non-negative integers, find three cells such that the sum of those cells and adjacent cells are as much as possible. If two chosen cells have common adjacent cells, the adjacent cells only participate once in the sum and two cells are considered adjacent if they share a common edge.

The naive brute force solutions runs in **O(n<sup>6</sup>)**. I have written a greedy solution that runs in **O(n<sup>4</sup>)**. The greedy solution uses this idea that the cell with maximum total sum of itself and its adjacent cells is always a part of the answer. I have tested both solutions on several test cases and the results are identical.

In greedy algorithm, first I choose the cell with maximum total sum of itself and adjacent cells and then iterate through all possible pair of cells.

Now my question is that, why this greedy strategy works? I want the proof. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you can abstract the matrix a bit more, with second matrix of equal size, where the value of the cell is equal to the sum of all adjacent cells.  Then from there, you can just find 3 largest sells which arent adjacent to each other, no?

Comment: @Fallenreaper No. Sometime we should choose adjacent cells. I think I explained the problem bad. I have to edit the statement "Each cell can only participate once in the sum" to "If two chosen cells have common adjacent cells, the adjacent cells only participate once in the sum".

Comment: That makes a bit more sense.  The issue then becomes: You should build a model yourself.  We can come up with the answer, but we dont want to inadvertently do your homework for you.

Comment: @Fallenreaper It's not homework.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work.  Sorry,

```
20  1 40  1 40  1 20
20  2 40  3 40  2 20
20  1 40  1 40  1 20
 1  1 20 20 20  1  1
 1  1 20  2 20  1  1
 1  1 20 20 20  1  1
```

The `3` has the highest sum of itself and all adjacent cells.  However picking the 3 cells of value `2` is actually best.

**Edit**

Apparently you meant something different from me by "adjacent".  So try this example:

```
 1  1  1  1  1  1  1
20  2 40  3 40  2 20
 1  1  1 20  1  1  1
 1  1 20  2 20  1  1
 1  1  1 20  1  1  1
 1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

Comment: No. Picking twos will get 210. The answer is 329.

Comment: Chooseing the cells (2,3), (2,5), and (5,4) will get 329. The cell (2,3) has the highest sum of itself and all adjacent cells.

Comment: @Chloe What do you mean by adjacent?  I was calculating it as "1 direction any way" which makes it a block of 9 cells."  I can update the example to break with a different definition of adjacent.